# Can "from" used to show a consequence?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning, adverbial-phrases

> They're affected from being unable to live their normal lives because areas of land are contaminated

I think "being unable to live their normal lives" is a consequence of being affected.
In other word, i think the result is being unable to live their lives

so, I have a question that whether "from" can be used to show a consequence.

the source is [here](https://reliefweb.int/report/world/cluster-munitions-have-prolonged-impact)

Comment: The "from" looks a bit off to me. I'd have been tempted to re-write it thus: "They're affected by their inability to live [their] normal lives ..."  It's very possible that the speaker is not a native English speaker and the journalist chose not to intervene too much by correcting his grammar. I can't answer your more general question except to say that 'from' is more likely to point from a cause rather than to a consequence.

Comment: Logically, if not grammatically, "being unable to live their normal lives" is the effect. The cause is contaminated land.

Comment: I note that in the original [un] is in square brackets. Perhaps the speaker meant _They are prevented from being able to live their normal lives_, but because he had said _affected_ the journalist corrected it to _unable_.

Comment: Do you mean the result is being unable to live their lives, or the cause is being unable to live their lives? Certainly "from" can be used with [a cause](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from), like "He caught a chill from being out in the cold" or "He was injured from the explosion" or "We can conclude from this that..." are fine. But "by" is more usual in this context with "affected by".

Comment: *They're **affected by** being **unable** to live there* OR *They're **prevented from** being **able** to live there*. But neither of those sentences actually include both cause and consequence. Note that when ***from*** is used in an utterance featuring both cause and consequence, it's "consequence **from** cause", as in ***He's tired from working so hard***.